# Why does the string come as an object React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I draw a string value through api and I want to print it in View. But the incoming string value comes as Promise. How can I prevent this?

"Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65,_55, _72}=. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

```
async getTitle(id) {        
    try {
        const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');            

        if(token) {
            var credentials = Base64.btoa(username + ':' + token);
            var URL         = `https://portal.xxxxx.com/api/v1/User/${id}`;
                
            var title = await axios.get(URL, {headers : { 'Espo-Authorization' : credentials }})
            .then((res) => {
                return <Text>{res.data.title}</Text>
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

            return title;
        }
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

<List
    contentContainerStyle={styles.listContentContainer}
    data={stream}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={Divider}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        item.type === "Post" ?
        <ListItem
            key={index}
            title={<Text><Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{item.createdByName}</Text> {this.getTitle(item.createdById)} {'\n'} <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{Moment(item.createdAt).add(3, 'hours').format('lll')}</Text>{'\n'}<Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }} status="warning">{this.statusLanguage(status)}</Text></Text>}
            description={<Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>{item.post}</Text>}
            accessoryLeft={renderCommentIcon}
        /> : null
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making an async call, the result is Promise. You can define a value with useState:

`[title, setTitle] = useState('');`

And you can use `setTitle` after your Promise is resolved. By doing so, your component will be rerendered and resulting title value can be shown in the view.

Comment: I already know this. But more than one of my items is coming. State can only hold 1 value.

Comment: Then instead of `title` use `titles` which is an array to hold all values.